# Problem with wget and Whitespace

Tags: wget

I have a bash script that scrapes a list of urls for links to various kinds of documents. At the end, the script uses `wget` to download the files. However, I'm having trouble with filenames containing white space in the name: `wget` ends the url at the space. Is there some way to use `sed` or something to change the white space to `%20` here? Or some other solution? 
This is my code:

```
for url in $(cat download.md)
do
    lynx --listonly --dump $url | \
awk '/\.(pdf|doc|docx|odt)$/{ sub("^[ ]*[0-9]+.[ ]*","",$0); print}'

done > ~/links.txt

for i in $( cat ~/links.txt ); do wget $i; 
done
```

Comment: I did, but it didn't work.

Comment: `wget "${i// /%20}"`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti also fails to download because the url is cut off at the space.

Comment: Based on the `for i in $( cat ... )` habit, I'd also recommend reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169765#169765

Comment: Thanks. I love how the example they laugh at is my actual code!

Comment: @Linter I'd be lying if I said I never wrote similar code (before learning safer ways!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost the full filenames during the `$( ... )` command substitution. Just ask `wget` to read the file directly:

```
wget -i ~/links.txt
```